# "does not have class type" error in the implementation of a class member function that uses a map container

Tags: c++

I've defined a class with a `map container` object called `aQueue`:

```
#include <map> 

using namespace std; 

class Class1
{
   private: 
      map<int,int, bool(*)(int,int)> aQueue(bool(*)(int,int));

   public: 
      bool isQEmpty(); 
};
```

In the implementation of `isQEmpty()`, I refer to the private variable `aQueue`, a `map` object,  to get its size:

```
bool Class1::isQEmpty()
{
   return (aQueue.size() == 0); //Uncompilable
}
```

The above implementation creates the error:
`error: '((Class1*)this)->Class1::aQueue' does not have class type`

Interpreting the error, it seems to me like the compiler doesn't know the class type of the object `aQueue` but clearly, I intended it to be a map

Answer (score 3):

```
map<int,int, bool(*)(int,int)>   aQueue(  bool(*)(int,int)  );
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
         Return type              Name      Argument type
```

That is a function. It's a function that takes a pointer to a function taking two `int`s and returns a `bool`, and returns a `map`.

`bool(*)(int, int)` is a type, which is why that is a function declaration. I'm assuming you wanted to pass a specific function in to it, like so:

```
map<int,int, bool(*)(int,int)> aQueue{&comparison_function};
```

Comment: That won't work in the class declaration. You could perhaps do `map<int,int, bool(*)(int,int)> qQueue = map<int,int, bool(*)(int,int)>(&comparison_function);`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Ah, thanks for pointing that out. If it uses braces instead of parenthesis, it works.

Comment: Can you show me how I could define the comparison behavior of a map on its keys in a class constructor?